# How do I combine matrices with files in C++?

Tags: c++, file, matrix

I am trying to create a program to combine two matrices. The first is to add them, the second is to subtract them, but I am getting an 1120 error. I don't know if that's because my code is bad, or if there's something wrong with my compiler. Here's what I've tried.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
fstream matrix_file("matricies.txt");
fstream result1_file("result1.txt");
fstream result2_file("result2.txt");

matrix_file.open("matricies.txt", ios::in);
if (!matrix_file) {
    cout << "File was not opened!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "File opened successfully!";
}
result1_file.open("result1.txt", ios::app);
if (!result_file) {
    cout << "File was not created!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "File created successfully!";
}
result2_file.open("result1.txt", ios::app);
if (!result_file) {
    cout << "File was not created!" << endl;
}
else {
    cout << "File created successfully!";
}
int matrix1[9];
int matrix2[9];
int result1Matrix[9];
int result2Matrix[9];

for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i)
{
    matrix_file >> matrix1[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    matrix_file >> matrix2[i];
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    result1Matrix[i] = matrix1[i] + matrix2[i]
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    result2Matrix[i] = matrix1[i] - matrix2[i]
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    result1_file >> result1Matrix[i] ;
}
for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
    result2_file >> result2Matrix[i];
}
matrix_file.close();
result1_file.close();
result2_file.close();
```

}

Comment: What is a "1120 error"? Please include all error messages in the question itself

Comment: Why are you opening the files twice, the second time in append mode (which makes little sense for a file you are trying to read from)?

Comment: Please include the content of your input file. Also explain what output do you expect.

Comment: `result_file >> resultMatrix[i] ;` is attempting to read data. Did you mean to write data using `<<` instead? You probably want to write a delimiter or whitespace between items as well if you want to be able to read them back. `result_file >> endl;` would definitely cause an error but I see you've edited that out.

Answer (score -1):

1. Line 35, 38: expected ';' in end line
2. Output file (result_file) must use operator '<<' instead of '>>'.